# Simple websocket for displaying an image to canvas

Tags: javascript, python, html, websocket, html5-canvas

I want to create an interactive application:

**Server (python):**
I want to create a simple websocket server in python which will be responsible for generating and feeding the socket with images.

**Client (HTML5, HTML5-canvas):**
I want to receive the images from the python websocket server and display them in an HTML5 canvas.

Does anyone has a similar example code?

Comment: Also consider [Server Sent Events](http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/) instead of Web Sockets, as they look a better fit for your requirements.

Comment: https://github.com/adicu/pantograph has an implementation of your usecase

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your use case is narrow so don't expect to find ready example code. If you are not familiar with WebSockets resort to generic tutorials. This is how it can be done:

1) Choose any Python Websocket library you wish

2) Send down images over the socket as binary messages

3) Parse images on the client side using Javascript Image object() dataURI source

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs

4) Draw imagees on `<canvas>`

Note that if you simply wish to display images one by one step 4 is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to start with a simple web socket but I encounter a lot of problems. Please check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053526/python-websocket-not-working`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my minimalistic example you might find useful:

[hello-websocket](https://github.com/vmlaker/hello-websocket)

It has an additional component of capturing images from a webcam. But the basics of client/server interaction are there.